# How to optimize a function with a constraint defined on a range?

Tags: optimization, constraints

I want to optimize a function $T(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ with the constraint that $g(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n,y)>0\quad \forall y \in [a,b], a,b \in R$. Both $T$ and $g$ are real-valued functions, defined on $R^n$ and $R^{n+1}$, respectively.

If my constraint was of the form $g(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)=c$ or $g(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\geq c$, I could use the method of Lagrangian multipliers. However, this is not the case here. Any ideas?

Comment: I would recommend [KKT-conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions).

Comment: Define a function $h(x_1,\dots,x_n)=\min_{y\in[a,b]}g(x_1,\dots,x_n,y)$. Then your constraint is equivalent to $h(x_1,\dots,x_n)>0$. You presumably can't obtain $h$ in closed form, but you can evaluate it numerically via a one-dimensional optimization, and I expect you could also get its gradient via implicit differentiation.